# Switch in C with while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

I am new to C programming. I wrote a simple switch case but it is not executing as expected . Can some one tell me what is wrong here??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char yes;
    bool flag = true;

    while(flag) {
        printf("Enter the value");
        scanf("%d",&i);

        switch(i) {
            case 1:
                printf("Hi");                       
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Hello");                        
                break;                      
        }

        printf("Enter Y or N to continue");
        scanf("%c",&yes);
        if (yes == 'N') {
            flag = false;       
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result I am expecting is:

```
Enter the Value
1
Hi
Enter Y or N to continue
Y
Enter the Value
2
Hello
Enter Y or N to continue
N
```

But the result I am getting is :

```
Enter the value 1
HiEnter Y or N to continueEnter the value N
HiEnter Y or N to continue
```

Comment: as it is a common user input mistake to enter a lower case letter when a capital letter was requested, the code to check for both lower and upper case or use 'toupper()' on the input char

Answer (score 7):

When you hit `Enter` after typing in the first number, `scanf` read all numeric characters from the input stream except the newline character produced by that `Enter` hit. The newline character is not a part of the number. It is left in the input stream, unread, waiting for someone else to read it.

The next `scanf("%c",&yes);` discovered that pending newline charcter and it read it without waiting. The `%c` format specifier does not skip whitespace in the input, it just reads the first character it sees.

Replace your `scanf` with

```
scanf(" %c",&yes);
```

to make it skip whitespace. That way it will ignore that pending newline and actually wait for you to enter something.

Answer (score 1):

In all your `printf` you need to add `\n` at the end.

For example on usage, see here: [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(You forgot all `'\n'` in your `printf` statements and add a `space` in your char `scanf` statements)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char yes;
    int flag = 1;

    while(flag) {
            printf("Enter the value\n");
            scanf("%d",&i);

            switch(i){

                case 1:
                    printf("Hi\n");                       
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("Hello\n");                        
                    break;          

            }

            printf("Enter Y or N to continue\n");
            scanf(" %c", &yes);
            if (yes == 'N')
                flag = 0;


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the Value
1
Hi
Enter Y or N to continue
Y
Enter the Value
2
Hello
Enter Y or N to continue
N
```

Comment: the code should also check the returned value from scanf() to assure that a number was actually entered.  Something like: if( 1 != scanf(" %c", &yes) ) { // handle error, exit}

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with the switch statement. It's a problem with your output - there aren't line breaks (`'\n'`). For example, instead of `printf("Hi");` you might want to have `printf("Hi\n");`, which adds a line space at the end.